# Navigation bar fica transparente quando o teclado é aberto em immersive mode

Tags: android, teclado, fullscreen

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em immersive mode, meu problema é quando o usuário vai inserir algum texto, quando o teclado abre a navigation bar e notificaton bar ficam transparente.

Este é o código que estou usando para deixar a aplicação em immersive mode:

private void setupMainWindowDisplayMode() {

```
 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

     decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new 

         View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

             @Override
             public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

                hideSystemUI();

        }
   });
 }


 private void hideSystemUI() {

 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(

            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Eu preciso que a navigation bar e notification bar apareçam normalmente quando o teclado estiver aberto.